# How to use angular.element to find and iterate over multiple elements?

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

I am writing a directive in `AngularJS` and one of the things I need to do is find all of the controls inside a form and iterate over them.

If `jQuery` was loaded I do this:

```
var inputs = element.find(".ng-invalid,.ng-valid");
inputs.each(function ()
{
    var i = $(this);               

});
```

But since it is not loaded and I just have `Angular` I can only think to do something like:

```
var inputs = element.find("input");
//for loop thru this
var selects = element.find("select");
//for loop thru this
//....etc
```

Is there some better way using jQLite to accomplish this?

Comment: How about the good, old, native `querySelectorAll()` ? What browsers do you need to support ?

Comment: Not certain yet. I may be able to live with IE8+ in which case this may be a decent solution.

Comment: you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542

Comment: Not sure how that is relevant. I am creating a *Directive*.

Answer (score 3):

If supporting IE7 or older is **[not a requirement](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)**, you can use the **[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll)** method of `Element`:

```
var controls = element[0].querySelectorAll('.ng-invalid, .ng-valid');
[].forEach.call(controls, function (ctl) {
    var c = angular.element(ctl);               
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a for-loop.

```
var inputs = element.find(".ng-invalid,.ng-valid");
for (var index=0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
  var subElement = angular.element(inputs)[index];
  // do something with subElement
}
```